# In Rails, how do I send a "new follower" email notification only one time in a given time period?

Tags: email, ruby-on-rails-3.1, notifications

I have an app with a follower model so that users can follow other users by clicking a "follow" button (and they can unfollow by clicking the "unfollow" button). **I want to send the newly followed user an email, but I only want to send that particular email once in a given timeframe.**

My concern is that I'm using AJAX to toggle the "follow" and "unfollow" buttons, and it would be very easy for a user (maliciously or otherwise) to just keep clicking that button repeatedly, thus sending "new follower" emails to a particular user. I also want to avoid emailing the newly followed person if the follow was accidental.

Here are a few use-cases that concern me. Let's say "John Doe" is the "new follower" and "Tommy" is the person who is followed by John Doe.

1. John Doe clicks "follow", realizes he didn't mean to follow Tommy, and quickly clicks "unfollow". In that case, I don't want to send the "new follower notification" to Tommy.
2. John Doe clicks "follow", thinks it's really nifty that the button automagically switched to "unfollow", and just starts clicking "follow", "unfollow", "follow", "unfollow" again and again. I don't want to spam Tommy with "new follower notification" emails every time John Doe clicks "follow". I only want to send that email to Tommy if John ends up following him after John is done playing with the button.

It seems like there are a couple things I could do.

1. To avoid toggling, I could disable the "follow" button for a beat (maybe one minute) after "unfollow" is clicked.
2. I could postpone the "new follower" email for a little bit (five minutes, an hour) and just double-check that the "follower" relationship still exists immediately before sending it. (This seems like a common thing to do, but I don't know how to do it.)
3. I could keep a record of which relationship triggered the email, and allow an email about that relationship only once per day. (This could be complicated since the relationship record is destroyed when "unfollow" is clicked. I'm not sure where I would store this.)

**Any suggestions on how to do this? I'm looking for conceptual suggestions and also specific technological suggestions ("Use such and such gem" or "Try this after_filter on the 'create' action in the relationships controller").**

Here's the code used to generate this email:

```
#relationships_controller.rb
class RelationshipsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate

  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:relationship][:followed_id])
    if current_user.follow!(@user)
      # Send new_follower email if followed user has opted in to that email
      UserMailer.new_follower_notification(@user, current_user).deliver if @user.master_switch && @user.new_follower_notification
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @user }
      format.js
    end

    def destroy
      ...
    end
  end

#user_mailer.rb
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def new_follower_notification(user, follower)
    @user = user
    @follower = follower
    mail(:from => "Example <example@example.com", :to => "#{@user.name} <#{@user.email}>", :subject => "#{@follower.name} (#{@follower.username}) is now following you!")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

- Create a new model.
- Add a timestamp every time someone clicks the "follow" button.
- When someone clicks the "follow" button, and if a timestamp exists, compare the DateTime.now to that time stamp.
- If it's under a certain minute/day/week range, don't send another email.

Comment: What do you have in mind for the new model. The main problem is that when a user "unfollows" another user, the record is destroyed completely (in the relationships table). So, there would never be a timestamp in the relationships table since a "follow" always creates a new record.

Comment: There are a lot of different ways to handle that. Here's one: do a soft delete **active=false** That way you still have the timestamp and can check it. Another way, which is a bit more work, would be to have a transactions table. Every follow is recorded, with a timestamp, user_id, etc... And this transaction table is referenced on every follow, verifying the amount of time since the last follow.